# Weird Issue with Missing Date Http Header

Tags: python, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, urlfetch

I have a python code that make a url request (within a googeappenigne environment):

```
urlfetch.fetch("http://path_to_my_servlet", 
headers={'Date': (now_datetime - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"),
         'X-This-Is-A-Header': now_datetime.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"))
```

I am testing it on my mac, and I see the request using wireshark, and the Date header is sent.

The URL is pointing to my servlet, that simply prints the headers:

```
        StringBuffer sb = 
           new StringBuffer("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTTP Headers</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>");
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        sb.append("<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>");
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            sb.append("<tr><td>");
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            sb.append(headerName).append("</td>");
            Enumeration<String> headerValues = request.getHeaders(headerName);
            boolean isFirst = true;
            while (headerValues.hasMoreElements()) {
                if (isFirst)
                    sb.append("<td>");
                else
                    sb.append("</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>\n");
                String headerValue = headerValues.nextElement();
                sb.append(headerValue);
                isFirst = false;
            }
            sb.append("</td></tr>");
        }

        sb.append("</table><br/></BODY></HTML>");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.print(sb.toString());
```

However, the date header is not printed. The servlet is running on Elastic beanstalk load balanced environment. and The output looks like this:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTTP Headers</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<table border='1'>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>host</td><td>myserver.elasticbeanstalk.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>accept-encoding</td><td>gzip</td></tr>
<tr><td>connection</td><td>Keep-Alive</td></tr>
<tr><td>x-forwarded-host</td><td>myserver.elasticbeanstalk.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>x-forwarded-server</td><td>myserverip.us-west-2.compute.internal</td></tr>
```

I attempted to send 'date' header instead (without the capital D), and even send an additional date custom header to see if it's printed. When adding date to the header from a browser using "postman" the date is printed.

Is my date format wrong and somehow filtered? Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: what operation are you using with postman?  From RFC 2616 - "Clients SHOULD only send a Date header field in messages that include an entity-body, as in the case of the PUT and POST requests, and even then it is optional."  Perhaps your server is ignoring the date header on your fetch.

Comment: I use the "GET" method in postman. A third-party I am using requires sending a Date header for authentication using "GET", and I am trying to debug an issue with the missing header. You think the tomcat removes this header?

Comment: It was just speculation based on the RFC.  You could try sending it as a post or a put and see if the header comes through, but if postman is using GET and the header is present, it sounds like a dead end.

Comment: It didn't help. The header is still not printed in post mode.